# Closures and Prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype

I am new to Javascript. I was trying hands on with closures and Prototype.

In the snippet below, min function is called but console.log(y) prints undefined.Why is that and also what object this.val will refer to?

```
function Air() {
  this.text = "Inside Air";

};

Air.prototype.min = function() {
  this.val = "Inside min";
  console.log("Inside min");
};

var x = new Air();
var y = x.min();
console.log(y);
```

In the second snippet, this code works fine.

```
 function Air() {
        console.log("InsiAir");
      return {
        min: function() {
          console.log("Inside min");
        }
      };
    }

var air = Air();
air.min();
```

While, this doesn't

```
function Air() {
    function min() {
        console.log("Inside Min");
    }

}

var air = Air();
air.min();
```

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening

Comment: `min` returns nothing.

Comment: So, by default it won't return a reference or something to that object?

Comment: @charlietfl function Air() {
    function min() {
        console.log("Inside Min");
    }

} This snippet also doesnot work for the same reason?

Comment: The last example doesn't work because `Air` doesn't return anything. Functions without a `return` statement always return `undefined` by default. You are simply declaring a local function `min` and return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

#### First snippet

```
function Air() {
  this.text = "Inside Air";
}

Air.prototype.min = function() {
  this.val = "Inside min";
  console.log("Inside min");
};

var x = new Air();
var y = x.min();
console.log(y);
```

You create a new `Air` object, which is assigned to `x`. Within the constructor, you set the new object's `text` property, which is not further used. Then, you call the `min` method on `x`, which is found on the prototype. Within that method, an instance property named `val` is set which is not used. `min` logs to the console. The `min` method returns nothing, which is the same as returning `undefined`. The value of `undefined` is thus assigned to the variable `y`. The value of `y`, which is `undefined`, is logged to the console.

#### Second snippet

```
function Air() {
   console.log("InsiAir");
   return {
     min: function() {
       console.log("Inside min");
     }
   };
 }

var air = Air();
air.min();
```

You call `Air()` and it returns an object. That object is assigned to the variable `air`. You invoke the `min` method on the object represented by `air`. Within the `min` function, it logs to the console. The `min` function returns nothing, which is the same as returning `undefined`. The returned value is ignored (although the console may print it).

#### Third snippet

```
function Air() {
  function min() {
    console.log("Inside Min");
  }
}

var air = Air();
air.min();
```

You call the `Air()` function, which returns nothing, which is the same as returning `undefined`. The value of `undefined` is assigned to the variable `air`. An attempt is made to call a method `min` on `undefined`, which results in a run-time error such as "Cannot read property `min` of undefined". `min` is a local function inside the `Air` function which can only be called from within `Air`, but is not, so it does nothing.

#### Closures

Nothing here has anything to do with closures, which in the sense that the term is generally used, refers to a situation in which some function accesses ("closes over") a variable in an outer scope. For instance, extending your second example:

```
 function Air() {
   var magic = 42;

   return {
     min: function() {
       return magic;
     }
   };
 }

var air = Air();
console.log(air.min());
```

The function/method `min` now "closes" over the variable `magic` in the outer scope. Even after `Air()` returns, the `min` method on the returned object can still access the `magic` variable, and so `42` will be logged to the console.

Answer (score 0):

> In first example:

```
function Air() {
   this.text = "Inside Air";
};

Air.prototype.min = function() {
  this.val = "Inside min";
  console.log("Inside min");
};

var x = new Air();
var y = x.min();
console.log(y);
```

It is displayed `undefined` because `min` function it doesn't return nothing.

if you use `var y=x.min()` and `min` function doesn't return nothing, then `y` variable will have `undefined` value.

If want to work, use simply:

```
var x = new Air();
x.min();
```

like `void` method.

> In the second snippet

`Air()`  returns nothing(undefined). The value of `undefined` is assigned to the variable `air`. Then, you will receive error when you try to access `min` method.

> In the last example,it is not working because you don't return anything.

```
function Air() {
    return {
        min() {
        console.log("Inside Min");
        }
    }
}
var air=Air();
air.min();
```

Comment: Okay, and to use closures do I always need to return inner function to use them?

Comment: @user3587856: Every function in JavaScript is technically a closure.

Comment: @FelixKling Can you please explain what you mean by every function is a closure?

Comment: @user3587856: A closure is a function that has a reference to the environment it was created in, to resolve free variables. Every function can do that in JavaScript, therefore every function is a closure. What do you mean by "use closures"?